# What is or would be an appropriate word to describe people deriving purpose from conflict?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you’ve seen Apocalypse Now, Restrepo or Hurt Locker, they’re all to some degree about soldiers who found more meaning/purpose from being in a state of war/conflict than being at peace.

Is there an existing English language word that describes this state of being?

EDIT: In a sentence - The person experiencing ________ desires conflict more than peace, as the conflict is familiar and motivating for them.

Comment: For a single-word-request question, you need to provide a sentence where you would use the word, leaving a blank for it ______

Comment: Also, contriving words is beyond the scope of the group.

Comment: Added an example sentence.

Comment: What is the hesitation to use prefixes and suffixes to create terms? If someone asked what’s appropriate Latin to express fear of dogs, you would say cynophobia, for example.

Comment: "Agent provocateur" may be close but not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: ELU deals with accepted usages. DIY 'words' cannot be checked for idiomaticity (or rather they're almost always non-idiomatic and hence unacceptable). Morphological mechanisms are not totiproductive.

Comment: @CraigMichael [That's not a term you just came up with on the spot.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cynophobia&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccynophobia%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth that’s just prescriptive grammar vs  descriptive grammar. Telling people how they should use English is fine, but it limits the the ability of English to evolve and express novel concepts.

Comment: @GArthurBrown that’s true, but the point is that it could be because the components of the word all make sense together. It’s how German works, too.

Comment: @ELL is not about how German works.

Comment: '[T]hat’s just prescriptive grammar vs descriptive grammar.' No, it's showing respect for the rules of the site. Other sites have different restrictions.

Comment: Welcome Craig, The veteran users here are a bit stuffy & stuck in their ways. I don't have an answer for this one but I love the question. I'm all about the evolution of the language too. @GArthurBrown "ELU is not about how German works" like a fat percentage of our dictionary isn't derived from Germanic roots (check fat) c'mon man (check: come, on, and, & man)

Comment: @Chauncey Don't be deliberately obtuse. It is not the purpose of ELL to contrive neologisms or to discuss the syntax or morphology of any language outside of English.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth read all of the rules presented to me before posting. I understand people who are fans of rules (grammar rules, stackoverflow rules, etc). But at the end of the day it’s wiser to err on the side of the spirit of the law rather than the letter of the law, or you end up like Javert.

Comment: @Chauncey thank you and yes! We borrow from every language! French, German, Yiddish, Latin, Greek, etc. Interesting concepts are not limited to the anglosphere. Amanda Palmer’s “French Brexit” song is especially good on this point.

Comment: @CraigMichael Many have claimed to uphold the spirit of the law as a justification for breaking the written law. If you want a contrived non-word to fill a lacuna, there are many websites more than willing to encompass such a desire. Please accept that trying to force ELU to be yet another can be interpreted as being selfish.

Comment: Many have claimed to uphold the spirit of the law as a justification for breaking the written law.[citation needed] Please accept that trying to force ELU to be yet another can be interpreted as being selfish by zombies.

Comment: Asking for helpful answers on a site built for answering questions is “selfish?” Like I said, read all rules presented before posting, followed all of them and the others that were asked. Direct your energy to improving the new user experience of you don’t like questions asked. Don’t retroactively impose new rules if you don’t like the questions, that’s selfish and entirely unreasonable.

Comment: There are terms like thrill-seeker and adrenaline junkie that describe a general desire for danger and excitement, although not so much single words. There are also terms for those who like war. But less combining both.

Comment: _Conflict-driven_ comes to mind but it doesn't exactly fit into your sentence. If you want terms more on the war/fighting side, there are _war spirit_ and _fighting spirit_. There are extended usages of _fighting spirit_ though, like a patient fighting a disease. They don't fit into the blank so I don't post as an answer.

Comment: Combat Stress Reaction or other medical conditions? I'm sure if you do some in-depth research you'll find papers and case studies about this.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Comment: @tchrist You got that right. Also, some of the requests are like "is there a word for hanging upside down from a branch when you feel ill but happy?"

Comment: [Transition stress](https://www.military.com/veteran-jobs/career-advice/military-transition/most-vets-ptsd-isnt-problem-transition-stress-heres-what-means.html) is the loss of purpose people feel when leaving the military, but it typically relates to the loss of order, discipline, structure, and purpose, rather than a love of chaos and destruction. I think the OP maybe doesn't have much idea of what the military is like.

Comment: @ermanen The question in the title asks for a way to describe the combative people; the fill-in-the-blank sentence asks for the thing they experience. IMHO, the question isn't properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that this is rather a toughie. But let me take a shot at it. A blanket term for a *conflict-desiring* person? Well, one could come up with a slew of adjectives such as *combative*, *bellicose*, *pugnacious*, and suchlike to describe such a tendency. But I believe that doesn't stay faithful to the demands of the question. Fortunately, this question is well within the remit of psychology, and one could justifiably argue that such a temperament is indeed describable.

The highly-accepted **Big Five Personality Traits** is a very useful taxonomy for personality traits. It whittles down the diverse personality traits to a nifty set of five— hence the name.

The Big Five traits outlined by the theory are:

1. Extraversion (outgoing/energetic vs. solitary/reserved)
2. Agreeableness (friendly/compassionate vs. critical/rational)
3. Openness to experience (inventive/curious vs. consistent/cautious)
4. Conscientiousness (efficient/organized vs. extravagant/careless)
5. Neuroticism (sensitive/nervous vs. resilient/confident)

> **Antagonism**, the low pole of *Agreeableness*, references traits related to immorality,
> combativeness, grandiosity, callousness, and distrustfulness. It is a robust correlate of
> externalizing behaviors such as antisocial behavior, aggression, and substance use; in fact, in
> many cases, it is the strongest trait correlate. It represents the core of many important and
> impactful psychopathological constructs (e.g., psychopathy, antisocial and narcissistic
> personality disorders). It is also central to models of general and disordered personality,
> psychopathology, and interpersonal behavior.

I believe **antagonism** faithfully captures the essence of a *conflict-desiring* personality.

Answer (score -1):

With a slight modification in your sentence, you could write:

> The [sanguinary](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/sanguinary) (or  [bloodthirsty](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/bloodthirsty)) person desires conflict more than peace....

Comment: This misses the importance of the meaning and purpose derived from being in conflict.